# Group by arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Aim**

Group tasks per employee/group of employees for which tasks were assigned to.

**Data Context**

- Each task can be assigned to more than one employee
- Each employee can have multiple tasks
- Values like employee `type` or `name` are just extra data, meaning it's the `employee_id` that distinguishes them

**Problem**

Currently, I am able to group the tasks per employee, not group of employees. If a task is shared by more than one employee, it is repeated on the array, like the example tasks below (appear in 2 employees groups: for `employee_id` `111` and `999` if you run the last code snippet that has both the initial data and my current code).

```
  {
    "task_employee_id": 10001,
    "task_name": "Maintenance",
    "task_url": "www.task_url10001.com",
    "status": "incomplete"
  },
  {
    "task_employee_id": 20002,
    "task_name": "Cleaning",
    "task_url": "www.task_url20002.com",
    "status": "completed"
  },
```

**Expected Result**

I should have it like this

```
groupTasks:  [
  {
    "employee_id": [{999},{111}]
    "type": "ABC",
    "name": "Lorem",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "task_employee_id": 10001,
        "task_name": "Maintenance",
        "task_url": "www.task_url10001.com",
        "status": "incomplete"
      },
      {
        "task_employee_id": 20002,
        "task_name": "Cleaning",
        "task_url": "www.task_url20002.com",
        "status": "completed"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "employee_id": 111,
    "type": "ZHG",
    "name": "Ipsum",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "task_employee_id": 30003,
        "task_name": "Fixing",
        "task_url": "www.task_url30003.com",
        "status": "incomplete"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "employee_id": 999,
    "type": "ABC",
    "name": "Lorem",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "task_employee_id": 40004,
        "task_name": "Checking",
        "task_url": "www.task_url40004.com",
        "status": "complete"
      }
   ]
  ]
```

Sidenote: it could either be `"employee_ids": [{"employee_id" :999},{"employee_id" : 111}]` or `"employee_id": [999,111]`

**Here is the code snippet with the initial data and my current code that doesn't ouput the expected result**

```js
const data = [
  {
    task_id: 10001,
    task_name: "Maintenance",
    task_url: "www.task_url10001.com",
    status: "incomplete",
    employees: [
      { employee_id: 999, type: "ABC", name: "Lorem" },
      { employee_id: 111, type: "ZHG", name: "Ipsum" }
    ]
  },
  {
    task_id: 20002,
    task_name: "Cleaning",
    task_url: "www.task_url20002.com",
    status: "completed",
    employees: [
      { employee_id: 111, type: "ZHG", name: "Ipsum" },
      { employee_id: 999, type: "ABC", name: "Lorem" }
    ]
  },
  {
    task_id: 30003,
    task_name: "Fixing",
    task_url: "www.task_url30003.com",
    status: "incomplete",
    employees: [{ employee_id: 111, type: "ZHG", name: "Ipsum" }]
  },
  {
    task_id: 40004,
    task_name: "Checking",
    task_url: "www.task_url40004.com",
    status: "complete",
    employees: [{ employee_id: 999, type: "ABC", name: "Lorem" }]
  }
];


// current approach

const groupTasks = [
  ...data
    .reduce(
      (
        groupTasksEmployees,
        {
          task_id: task_employee_id,
          task_name,
          task_url,
          status,
          employees = []
        }
      ) => {
        employees.forEach(({ employee_id, type, name }) => {
          const employees = groupTasksEmployees.get(employee_id) ?? {
            employee_id,
            type,
            name,
            tasks: []
          };
          employees.tasks.push({
            task_employee_id,
            task_name,
            task_url,
            status
          });
          groupTasksEmployees.set(employee_id, employees);
        });
        return groupTasksEmployees;
      },
      new Map()
    )
    .values()
];
console.log("groupTasks: ", groupTasks);
```

Comment: What's your expected result, the first json or the 2nd one?

Comment: @DreamBold the expected result is the one under Expected Result. The last code snippet just shows the initial data and my current code. If you run it you can see that it doesn't output the expected result

Comment: If task `20002` has another employee `333` for example:  `{ employee_id: 333, ... }`, what is the expected output in that case?

Comment: @NickParsons If task `2002`and `1001` have also employee `333` besides `111` and `999` , after grouping, the `employee_id` related to that task should show  `"employee_id": [{999},{111},{333}]` or `"employee_id": [999,111,333]`

Comment: `[{999},{111},{333}]` is invalid and will throw an error

Comment: @user1128912 so if you had 333 as another employee of 20002, then in the result, the first group would be `[999,111]` (note: you cannot have `[{999}, {111}]` as that's not a valid JS structure), which would just have 1 task of   `Maintenance`, and then the second group would be `[999, 111, 333]` which would have just 1 task of `Cleaning` in that case?

Comment: @NickParsons @James you are right about `[{999}, {111}]`. I've updated it to `"employee_id": [{"employee_id" :999},{"employee_id" : 111}]` // `"employee_id": [999,111]` I will clarify the rest on the next comment

Comment: In your expected result, employee 111 has the type ZGH but is in type ABC for group [111,999]. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Brother58697 it doesn't matter because different employee types can perform the same task. It's just some extra data. The ID is what distinguishes them

Comment: @NickParsons the sample data is a bit simplified but yes, employee `333` could have the same task as `111` and `999` but done for example at a different time, so he would be separated from the group. At some point `111`and `999` were assigned together to do something and later on `333`was assigned to do the same apart. So `111`and `999`should be grouped together and `333`should have his own "individual group". The tasks can be repeated by different employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, obtained by a slight modification of your code, could be:

```js
const data = [
    {
        task_id: 10001,
        task_name: "Maintenance",
        task_url: "www.task_url10001.com",
        status: "incomplete",
        employees: [
            { employee_id: 999, type: "ABC", name: "Lorem" },
            { employee_id: 111, type: "ZHG", name: "Ipsum" }
        ]
    },
    {
        task_id: 20002,
        task_name: "Cleaning",
        task_url: "www.task_url20002.com",
        status: "completed",
        employees: [
            { employee_id: 111, type: "ZHG", name: "Ipsum" },
            { employee_id: 999, type: "ABC", name: "Lorem" }
        ]
    },
    {
        task_id: 30003,
        task_name: "Fixing",
        task_url: "www.task_url30003.com",
        status: "incomplete",
        employees: [{ employee_id: 111, type: "ZHG", name: "Ipsum" }]
    },
    {
        task_id: 40004,
        task_name: "Checking",
        task_url: "www.task_url40004.com",
        status: "complete",
        employees: [{ employee_id: 999, type: "ABC", name: "Lorem" }]
    }
];


// current approach

const groupTasks = [
    ...data
        .reduce(
            (
                groupTasksEmployees,
                {
                    task_id: task_employee_id,
                    task_name,
                    task_url,
                    status,
                    employees = []
                }
            ) => {
                let employee_ids = employees.map(o=>o.employee_id).sort();
                const employee_ids_unique = employee_ids.join('_'),
                    type = employees[0]?.type,
                    name = employees[0]?.name;
                if(employee_ids.length === 1){
                    employee_ids = employee_ids[0];
                }
                
                const employees_g = groupTasksEmployees.get(employee_ids_unique) ?? {
                    employee_id: employee_ids,
                    type,
                    name,
                    tasks: []
                };
                employees_g.tasks.push({
                    task_employee_id,
                    task_name,
                    task_url,
                    status
                });
                groupTasksEmployees.set(employee_ids_unique, employees_g);
                return groupTasksEmployees;
            },
            new Map()
        )
        .values()
];
console.log("groupTasks: ", groupTasks);
```

This seems to produce your expected result, including the selection of only one `name` and one `type` in the aggregated data. It could easily be modified to include all employee `name`s and `type`s for each task that contains more than one employee.

Comment: thank you, it worked. I've changed to `type = employees.map((o) => o.type),
name = employees.map((o) => o.name)` to test what you were saying about being easy to update it to show all names and types and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Make a key from all of the employee ids and use that to refer to the group in the reduce accumulator.

```
   const output = data.reduce((acc, {employees, ...rest}) => {
      const group = employees.map(e => e.employee_id).sort();
      const key = group.join('_');
      if(!acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = {
          id: group,
          tasks: []
        };
      }
      acc[key].tasks.push(rest);
      return acc;
   }, {});
   const arr = Object.values(output);
```

Comment: it worked, thank you. I voted the other answer as solution because both worked and the other one came first. Also, with my lack of knowledge, I could easily add all the names and types also.